Inconsistent Transaction Status in Tact Smart Contract Testing
I'm working on testing a smart contract in the Tact language and encountering an issue with the transaction status reporting. When using printTransactionFees(result.transactions) to check the transaction details, it indicates that the transaction failed with the expected exit code. However, my assertion check for the transaction status is not behaving as expected:
expect(result.transactions).toHaveTransaction({
    from: hashedTimeLockTON.address,
    to: receiver,
    success: false,
});

This assertion is supposed to confirm that the transaction failed, but it fails by indicating success: true. Could there be an underlying reason for this discrepancy where the transaction is marked as successful despite a failure exit code? What could be causing this, and how can I accurately check the transaction status in such cases?
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

By looking at the implementation code of toHaveTransaction, we can know that the bottom layer uses the Arrays.some method, so as long as one of the arrays is true, all are true. This is a flaw. I think the bottom layer should use the every method better.
function compareTransactionForTest(subject, cmp) {
    if (Array.isArray(subject)) {
        return {
            pass: subject.some(tx => compareTransaction(flattenTransaction(tx), cmp)),
            posMessage: ((subj, cmp) => `Expected ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(subj.map(tx => flattenTransaction(tx)))} to contain a transaction that matches pattern ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(cmp)}`).bind(undefined, subject, cmp),
            negMessage: ((subj, cmp) => `Expected ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(subj.map(tx => flattenTransaction(tx)))} NOT to contain a transaction that matches pattern ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(cmp)}, but it does`).bind(undefined, subject, cmp),
        };
    }
    else {
        try {
            const flat = flattenTransaction(subject);
            return {
                pass: compareTransaction(flat, cmp),
                posMessage: ((flat, cmp) => `Expected ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(flat)} to match pattern ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(cmp)}`).bind(undefined, flat, cmp),
                negMessage: ((flat, cmp) => `Expected ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(flat)} NOT to match pattern ${(0, node_inspect_extracted_1.inspect)(cmp)}, but it does`).bind(undefined, flat, cmp),
            };
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (subject.transactions !== undefined) {
                console.warn('It seems that a SendMessageResult is being used for this comparison. Please make sure to pass `result.transactions` instead of just `result` into the matcher.');
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
exports.compareTransactionForTest = compareTransactionForTest;


So your approach is to use this function instead of tohaveTransaction ?
